# Is there a decent alternative to "pip bundle"?

Tags: python, pip

I use `pip bundle` for my production systems, and today I was greeted with the following disheartening message:

```
###############################################
##                                           ##
##  Due to lack of interest and maintenance, ##
##  'pip bundle' and support for installing  ##
##  from *.pybundle files is now deprecated, ##
##  and will be removed in pip v1.5.         ##
##                                           ##
###############################################
```

My servers auto-scale and build themselves out automatically, but I've been burned before by relying on PyPi being available. Instead, I use `pip bundle` and commit the .pybundle file to the source git repo. This means I only need to rely on a single source for building my servers.

With `pip bundle` going away (and who knows when) I need an alternative method to use - are there any suggestions or similar methods of packaging up dependencies for production distribution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the new [wheel format](https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/); `wheel` builds on `pip` to bundle packages into a ZIP format.

Alternatively, you could install an egg proxy; we use [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/) together with a local egg proxy to manage package dependencies and versioning in development and production enviroments.

Comment: `pip wheel` seems to get me 90% of the way there, except for any git-based "dependencies in the format of `-e git+git@your.gitserver.com:/repo.git#egg=repo` - I'll check out Buildout

Comment: Appears that if I change my git repo pointers to `git+https://...` things work smoothly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is how we ended up going about it: http://tech.flyclops.com/replacing-pip-bundle-374

Comment: The link in the above comment should be https://tech.flyclops.com/posts/2013-09-20-replacing-pip-bundle.html

Answer (score -2):

Use [pip-bundle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip-bundle), it does pretty the same:

instead of

```
pip bundle -q mybundle.pybundle -r python-requirements.pip
```

you write:

```
pip-bundle create mybundle.pybundle -r python-requirements.pip
pip-bundle install mybundle.pybundle
```