# Unable to install cherrypy on an offline server

Tags: python, pip, cherrypy

Good Morning everyone, I am attempting to install CherryPy on a server without internet access. It has windows Server 2012. I can RDP to it, which is how i have attempted to install it. The server has Python 2.7 installed.

What I have tried (unsuccessfully):

RDP to the server, pip install cherrypy from command line (issue is that it is offline)

Downloaded the .grz files, RDP to server, from CL ran python (source to the setup.py file) install. says that there are dependencies that are unable to be downloaded (because offline).

Downloaded the whl file, attempted to run, did not work.

Is there a way to download the the package, along with all dependencies, on a remote computer (with internet access) and them copy the files over and install? I have attempted to find this information without success.

thank you all for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a decent alternative to "pip bundle"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905314/is-there-a-decent-alternative-to-pip-bundle)

Answer (score -2):

Ended up copying my entire lib\site-packages folder to the remote server, placed where it would have been on my old server, and it worked fine.

TL:DR copy you %Python_home%/lib/site-packages folder to your remote machine and it might work. need to have the same version of python installed. In my case it was 2.7.

Comment: Use [installation bundles](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installation-bundles)